# InternetOpenUrl in asynchronous mode

Tags: c++, asynchronous, callback, msdn, wininet

I have a function that asynchronously downloads a file using WinINet functions. The approach I use is:

- [InternetOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [InternetSetStatusCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [InternetOpenUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (synchronously)
- [InternetReadFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (async)
- InternetReadFileEx in the callback function until the received buffer is 0

How can I wait until `InternetOpenUrl` is done so the handle returned is valid?  If I run `InternetOpenUrl` async, I can't tell when I receive the last [`INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because of possible redirections. Also when `InternetOpenUrl` is done I want to call [`InternetQueryOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `INTERNET_OPTION_URL` flag, to get the final URL after all redirections, if any.

```
std::vector<DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT> contexts;

void Download(TCHAR *url, unsigned int crc32, unsigned int length)
{
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(_T("Test"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    InternetSetStatusCallback(hInternet, DownloadProgress);
    DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT context;
    context.hInternet = hInternet;
    contexts.push_back(context);
    HINTERNET hUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, url, _T(""), 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, DWORD_PTR(&*(contexts.end()-1)));
    /* if InternetOpenUrl would have been executed in blocking mode,
       here I would have executed the first async InternetReadFileEx,
       and InternetQueryOption to get the final URL*/
}

void CALLBACK DownloadProgress(
    _In_  HINTERNET hInternet,
    _In_  DWORD_PTR dwContext,
    _In_  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
    _In_  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
    _In_  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
    )
{
    DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT *context = (DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT*)dwContext;
    switch (dwInternetStatus)
    {
    case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED:
        context->hUrl = (HINTERNET)((LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT)lpvStatusInformation)->dwResult;
        break;

    case INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED:
        size = 0;
        InternetQueryOptionA(context->hUrl, INTERNET_OPTION_URL, nullptr, &size);
        link = new char[size];
        InternetQueryOptionA(context->hUrl, INTERNET_OPTION_URL, link, &size);
        MessageBoxA(NULL, link, "", MB_OK);
        delete[] link;
        /* if this is the last response (the HTTP status code is 200)
           we initiate InternetReadFileEx recursion */
        break;

    ...

    default:
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Status: Unknown (%d)\n", "", MB_OK);
        break;
    }
}
```

Also some WinINet functions will fail with `ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE`, inside the callback since `InternetOpenUrl` is not done yet. Although `InternetQueryOption` does show the URL at every `INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED`.

`InternetOpenUrl` will generate the following sequence of callback statuses:

- INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED
- INTERNET_STATUS_DETECTING_PROXY
- INTERNET_STATUS_SENDING_REQUEST
- INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_SENT
- INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE
- INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED
- INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT
- INTERNET_STATUS_DETECTING_PROXY
- INTERNET_STATUS_RESOLVING_NAME
- INTERNET_STATUS_NAME_RESOLVED
- INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTING_TO_SERVER
- INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTED_TO_SERVER
- INTERNET_STATUS_SENDING_REQUEST
- INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_SENT
- INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE
- INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED

How can I tell when the last `INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED` has arrived (HTTP status 200)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is no need to run `InternetOpenUrl` synchronously. The problem was that I didn't actually run asynchronously, because I forgot to set the `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` flag in `InternetOpen`.

When you run asynchronously there is one more callback status received, `INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE`, which indicates that an asynchronous operation has finished. When you receive this, it's safe to call `InternetReadFile` in a recursive fashion, because when `InternetReadFile` is done you'll receive another `INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE`, which in turn will call `InternetReadFile` again. You do this until `dwResult` of `INTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT` is false.

It is also possible that `InternetReadFile` will run synchronously if there is a lot of buffered data, at which point you'll have to run again `InternetReadFile` until a call to `GetLastError()`, right after `InternetReadFile`, does NOT result to `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. After that you close the handles and you're done.

```
typedef struct{
    HWND        hDialog;      // Window handle
    HINTERNET   hUrl;    // HINTERNET handle created by InternetOpenUrl
    char        buffer[512];
    DWORD       size; // buffer fill size
    unsigned int crc32;
    unsigned int length; // file length
    unsigned int received; // downloaded bytes so far
} DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT;

std::vector<DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT> contexts;

void Download(TCHAR *url, unsigned int crc32, unsigned int length)
{
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(_T("Test"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC); // async flag
    InternetSetStatusCallback(hInternet, DownloadProgress);
    DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT context;
    context.hDialog = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hMainWindow, DownloadDlg);
    context.length = length;
    context.crc32 = crc32;
    context.received = 0;
    context.size = 0;
    contexts.push_back(context);
    HINTERNET hUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, url, _T(""), 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, DWORD_PTR(&*(contexts.end()-1)));
}

void CALLBACK DownloadProgress(
    _In_  HINTERNET hInternet,
    _In_  DWORD_PTR dwContext,
    _In_  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
    _In_  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
    _In_  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
    )
{
    DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT *context = (DOWNLOAD_CONTEXT*)dwContext;
    switch (dwInternetStatus)
    {
    case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED:
        context->hUrl = (HINTERNET)((LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT)lpvStatusInformation)->dwResult;
        ShowWindow(context->hDialog, SW_SHOW);
        break;

    case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING:
        // clean up
        break;

    case INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED: // don't need to do anything here
        break;

    case INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE:
        if ((HINTERNET)((LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT)lpvStatusInformation)->dwResult == context->hUrl)
        {
            DWORD size = 0;
            char *text;
            InternetQueryOptionA(context->hUrl, INTERNET_OPTION_URL, nullptr, &size);
            text = new char[size];
            InternetQueryOptionA(context->hUrl, INTERNET_OPTION_URL, text, &size);
            SetWindowTextA(GetDlgItem(context->hDialog, IDC_EDIT1), text);
            delete[] text;
        }
        if (((LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT)lpvStatusInformation)->dwResult > 0)
        {
            bool res;
            do
            {
                context->received += context->size;
                // proccess first size bytes from buffer
                res = InternetReadFile(context->hUrl, context->buffer, 512, &context->size);

            } while (res && context->size > 0);
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
                InternetCloseHandle(context->hUrl);
            }

            SetWindowTextA(GetDlgItem(context->hDialog, IDC_STATIC_SIZE), to_string(context->received).c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
            InternetCloseHandle(context->hUrl);
        }
        break;

    ...

    default:
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Status: Unknown (%d)\n", "", MB_OK);
        break;
    }
}
```